# how to get all features from a layer in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, wms

I deal with geoserver and openlayers,

i use WMS layer for displaying due to loading time is shorter than vector layer.

My problem i couldn't get all features of a layer without event,

For sure i tray "getfeatureinfo" but it's return selected point not all

And i try to use vector layer for getting the features, But it not work unless i add it to the map ,

which will take long long time in loading .!

could any one help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try with the getfeatureinfo request.

There is this line:

```
FEATURE_COUNT: 1,
```

here instead of 1 you could write the total number of your features, but this way you still have to click on the map to get them

I hope this helps